# PPL Task - Continuation in UI thread for desktop application

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, ppl

I would like to use a ppl task to do some work in the background, and, upon completion, show the result in a window. In my case the UI-framework is MFC. The structure would be:

```
using namespace concurrency;

create_task([] {
    // this can be run in any thread, shouldn't be the UI thread
    // do real work here
    return 42;
}).then([](int n)
{
    // this should be run on the UI thread
    // ... open a MFC window to display results
});
```

The thing is, a non Windows Store app doesn't allow to specify the task_continuation_context. Instead, the runtime decides which context will be used (see [task_continuation_context Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh749968%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
Can I rely on the runtime to reliably figure out that it needs to run the continuation on the UI thread? Is there a reasonable workaround to achieve what I want - without blocking the UI thread?

---

**Update:** Playing around showed that the runtime will not run the continuation on the UI thread. So, is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this was to create a Dispatcher class and a message-only window, which is a member of the Dispatcher. The Dispatcher must be constructed (I used a singleton) from the main thread such that the main thread takes care of the messages which are sent to the message-only window. I can pass a `std::function` to my `Dispatcher::ExecuteInMainThread` function. The Dispatcher will then invoke `SendMessage` on the message-only window, passing in the pointer (unfortunately only a pointer will be possible) to the `std::function`. The only message handler I need in the message-only window will then invoke the function I passed in - within the main thread.

This Dispatcher can be used in the task continuation to execute a `std::function` in the main thread.

Comment: could you provide a source code example of what you did? I am trying to find out the way to do this and am running into MSDN circular reference hell, spiraling into the dark pit of MSDN no-help-whatsoever-despair.